# Order By with Union and null values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am at a loss of how to sort the data in the second select statement of the following union query.

The desired results would be:

```
C null null null null null
I xxxx xxxx xxxx 1    xxxx
I xxxx xxxx xxxx 1    xxxx
I xxxx xxxx xxxx null xxxx
I xxxx xxxx xxxx null xxxx
```

Here is the code:

```
select 'C' [Identifier]
,null [Acct/Invoice #]
,null [Check #/Pay Amount]
,null [Check Amount/Error Code]
,null [Error Flag]
,null [Trx Account #]
union all
select 'I' [Indentifer]
,final_inv_number [Invoice #]
,final_final_pay_amount [Pay Amount]
,final_trans_code [Error Code]
,case when final_is_reconciled = 1 then 1 end [Error Flag]
,case when final_parse_type = 'ERROR CREATED' or final_parse_type = 'PREV PD'
    then final_account_number else null end [Trx Account #]
from #final
where final_net_pay_amount <> 0
--order by [Error Flag] ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting the entire result, not just the records from the second select.

You can use the [Identifier] field to keep the records from the first select first:

```
order by [Identifier], [Error Flag] desc
```

Comment: This is a good answer for this case, so +1. I had not seen that `[Identifier]` is a constant here.

Comment: O_o OK, this is what I *thought* I had tried previously and was getting a syntax error, although it is working perfectly now :) Thanks for the help! ...I guess it's just one of those days...

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` is computed after `UNION ALL` or other set operators. Therefore you should use subselects run `ORDER BY` on those subselect statements, compute a pseudocolumn that assigns an increasing row number, and then order by the value of the pseudocolumn in the outer statement.

Comment: @Lucero: without `ORDER BY` the RDBMS is free to output the rows in any order. `UNION ALL` merges two sets, does not filter out duplicate rows, but technically there is no guarantee that your subsets come out one after the other.